# How to add the slide down and bounce animation perfectly in android?

Tags: android, xml, animation

I am trying to animate a TextView which slides down from the top to the center and then bounce and stay stagnant. I have put a code and it bounces perfectly but the problem I am having is that its not showing the slide down effect. The text just appears after the animation duration finishes and then bounces. The code in xml is put below:

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shareInterpolator="false"
android:fillAfter="false">

<translate
    android:duration="1000"
    android:fillAfter="true"
    android:fromYDelta="-100%p"
    android:toYDelta="0%p"/>

<scale
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/bounce_interpolator"
    android:duration="500"
    android:fillAfter="true"
    android:fromXScale="1.0"
    android:fromYScale="0.0"
    android:startOffset="1000"
    android:toXScale="1.0"
    android:toYScale="1.0"/>
```

If anyone can help me get through with this it would be great.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are using

```
android:toYDelta="0%p"
```

this is what causing you the problem. You have used this probably because you have centered your TextView in the screen. So in my opinion you should not centered your TextView in your layout and do something like this in your xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
>
   <TextView 
   android:id="@+id/tv_text"
   android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
   android:text="23"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   />
```

and then change your set animation to this

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:fillAfter="true"
android:shareInterpolator="false" >

<translate
    android:duration="1000"
    android:fromYDelta="-100%p"
    android:toYDelta="50%p" 
    />

<scale
    android:duration="500"
    android:fromXScale="1.0"
    android:fromYScale="0.0"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/bounce_interpolator"
    android:startOffset="1000"
    android:toXScale="1.0"
    android:toYScale="1.0" />

</set>
```